# java jain sip how to minimize transaction timeout

Tags: java, sip, voip, jain-sip, jain-slee

I'm building a Jain Sip application that sends request and receives response.
In case the response is not received I need to handle it in my code, but the default delay before firing the processTimeout function is too long (~32 sec), how can I minimize it?

below is a snippet of my code:

```
//Sending the request statfully:
sendRegisterStateful{
ClientTransaction transaction = this.sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
// Send the request statefully, through the client transaction.
transaction.sendRequest();

//Process timeout function:
public void processTimeou{
//Need to fire the timeout here after 7sec instead of ~32s
}
```

Thank you,
Salim

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by editing the timer factor in SIPTransaction class (Jain Sip Lib):
The original value was 64 , new value became 14:
Formula:
Timeout ms  = timeout_factor*T1 //T1 is the retranmission time default: 500ms; timeout factor default: 64.
Defalut timeout value in millisecond = 500*64 = 32000ms
So I minimized the value of 64 in order to minimize the default time out 32000ms -> 7000ms

```
class SIPTransaction{ 
......
protected static final int TIMER_B = 14;

protected static final int TIMER_J = 14;

protected static final int TIMER_F = 14;

protected static final int TIMER_H = 14;
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the preferred way to do things. You should not need to edit code. Set the base timer interval for your transaction. Look through the Transaction API to see how to do that.

Comment: Transaction API don't expose functions to adjust the transaction time out.